# R, Caret: save/load parallel random forest fails

Tags: r, load, random-forest, predict, r-caret

I ran into an issue when working with parallel random forests in caret (R). I saw that they are multiple question that seem to deal with the same problem, after reading through the answer I'm however still stuck with the same problem.

I have a dataset which I use to train a model like this:

```
rfParam <- expand.grid(mtry = 5)
parRFModel <- train(
    form = Class~.,
    data = datasetShorted,
    method="parRF",
    tuneGrid = rfParam
    )
```

I can use this model to predict, using the following command:

```
predictions <- extractPrediction(list(parRFModel), testX = datasetShorted[1:10,2:numFeatures])
```

Then I save the model:

```
save(parRFModel, file="parRFModel-MTry5.RData")
```

The problem is when I'm restarting R, reloading all the libraries and then executing

```
load("parRFModel-MTry5.RData")
```

The model is loaded correctly but I'm unable to predict:

```
> parRFModel
Parallel Random Forest 

40794 samples
 1947 predictors
    8 classes: '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 

Summary of sample sizes: 40794, 40794, 40794, 40794, 40794, 40794, ... 

Resampling results

  Accuracy   Kappa     Accuracy SD  Kappa SD 
  0.6877108  0.477487  0.004078363  0.0072271

Tuning parameter 'mtry' was held constant at a value of 5

> predictions <- extractPrediction(list(parRFModel), testX = datasetShorted[1:10,2:numFeatures])
Error in UseMethod("predict") : 
  no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "randomForest"
> class(parRFModel)
[1] "train"         "train.formula"
```

Do you have any idea, why this happens? Is there something wrong with the save/load functionality? Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of `caret` and `R` is this? Did you also try using `predict(parRFModel, datasetShorted[1:10,2:numFeatures])`. It looks like the `randomForest` package isn't loaded. Please give us the results of `sessionInfo()` after the crash.

Comment: You are a hero! Turns out I was loading randomForest indirectly, when calling train but in the second instance it wasn't loaded and that is why it crashed. Calling library(randomForest) first, solved the problem. Thank you so very much! P.S. Also it is probably not relevant, this is the newest version caret_6.0-37, R version 3.0.2 and randomForest_4.6-10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to make the answer explicit so it's easier for the next viewer:

Make sure you call `library(randomForest)` before trying to use the `predict` method. This will ensure that the `randomForest` package is loaded, and therefore the `predict` method is defined for objects of class `randomForest`.